# Select a property from duplicate records in ef core linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a database that contains duplicate records, but only their ID field is the same and the rest of their information is different for example:

```
Id: test, version: 1.0.0
Id: test, version: 2.1.3
Id: something, version: 4.0.0
Id: something, version: 5.0.0
...
```

I can get all items without duplication with the following codes

```
using var db = new dbContext();
            var query =
                from item in db.my.Select(x => new { x.Id }).Distinct()
                .SelectMany(key => db.myTable.Where(x => x.Id == key.Id).Take(1))
            select new myModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Versions = <Here we need all related versions>
                };

            return await query.ToListAsync();
```

Now I want to get all versions of an ID and put it in the `Versions` in `select new myModel{}`

But I do not know how to do this

UPDATE:
i added this line to query

```
from versions in db.myTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Id)
```

and

```
select new myModel
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    Versions = versions.Select(x => x.Version).ToList()
                };
```

but i got an error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
```

Comment: What is `Versions`? If it's a list of the `my` entity class instances, then switch back to the original solution with `GroupBy` performed in memory (`AsEnumerable().GroupBy(...)`). The solution for the previous question was for returning *single* item per unique `Id`. It's good to know in advance exactly what do you need as result, since unfortunately the approaches are different.

Comment: Versions is List<String>, As you answered in the previous post, Now in addition, I want to get versions of each id

Comment: I mean, I need both, a non-duplicate list, and each item with its own version

Comment: So do that in memory as proposed in other answer. Anyway too many questions for such simple task.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv i updated my question, i used memory method but I got an error. Your method and memory method do not seem to be combined

Answer (score 1):

This requires different approach than the one for returning single item per group.

The required operation here makes no sense to be implemented server side, hence should be done client side, with the only potential optimization of not retrieving unneeded data from the database.

First, use server side query to select all data needed. Then materialize that query in memory and perform `GroupBy` and final projection there.

e.g.

```
var dbQuery = db.my.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    x.Version,
});

var data = await dbQuery.ToListAsync();

var result = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => new myModel
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Versions = g.Select(x => x.Version).ToList(),
    });
```

Comment: thank you and if i want to get another fields like name i should write this? `Name = g.Select(x => x.Name).First(),`

Comment: Yes, you could. Everything after executing the db query and storing the result in memory runs in regular LINQ to Objects context, where basically everything that compiles successfully works.